# Text File or Database based chat room? Not only messages and not only one-to-one

Tags: database, json, performance, file, chat

I'm developing a webchat and I have to decide what strategy to use. I can use either a text file or a database to store the data that come from and go to the users.

Yes, I've seen the other posts where people are talking about it, but I have a few more questions than just "which one is faster" (that's also one of my questions, but not the only one). And I will point out the problem more carefully.

First of all many users will share the same room and chat with all the others at the same time. Many rooms will be open at the same time (the same user can be at two rooms at the same time).

In this system messages is not the only thing that come and go. The status (away, online, typing etc), updates ("don't talk to me, i had the worst day of my life" or "i'm new here"), who logged out and in, replies to other messages, and the messages themselves are the kind of traffic that will be there. Somewhere.

I want the Javascript to receive the data in JSON format.

And I want this chat to be used by many many people at the same time! Will send requests from each one of them every 5 or 10 seconds.

Some data will be stored in the Database for sure (the user sessions, its id, the user's id, information about the room, when it was created etc), but how it will deal with dynamic data flow is still to be decided.

In other words, even if it's not the most complex chat ever developed, it's not the simplest one.

Example of files distribution if strategy chosen is text file:
Path: /root/room/1 (to room 1)
Files: 1000001, 100002, 100003 (users in this room)

Path: /root/room/2
Files: 1000002, 100005, 100010

...

Messages and any other kind of update (access, status, personal update etc) sent in room 1 FROM user 1000001 will be saved in paths /root/room/1/100002 (user 2) and /root/room/1/100003 (user 3) and so on.

Each user will read his own file for that room and erase it after reading so only new data will be in that files everytime they read them.

The data is written in JSON format so no further encoding is needed.

The questions:
1- Considering a huge traffic of data being written in and read from these text files, what is the best option, using the database to save the file and then make queries (SELECT FROM messages (and from update, and from access, and from anything else) WHERE id > #number) every 5 or 10 seconds, for each user in each room, or using the text files?

2- If the Database is the best option, should I write it in JSON format? I would use a field called JSON, because I wouldn't want to loose the ability of making queries in that database. Or maybe I would create a new table, connecting the user, the room and the JSON and write AGAIN in other tables to keep the tuple format.

3- if File is the best option, would you consider replicating the data in the database (just in case you want to query or whatever) everytime it's saved in the files?

Comment: I've really got to wonder why you think you want to hit disk at all.  What's the point of persisting the messages?  If you decide to persist them, what's wrong with keeping a single log of all events that have happened?

Comment: the files must be stored somewhere at least for a little time so other users can get them.

other reasons for saving them somewhere: messages can be a reply to another message. so how would the users (remember that a room has many users exchanging messages and messages are broadcasted) know what message is a message's parent?

A -> B. if B is received and A is an old message, they must search somewhere for A. it must be saved in the disk somewhere. the memory isn't a good choice because of overflow